# Bipartite regular (connected) graphs: Cocliques of maximum size (using purely combinatorial arguments)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a regular bipartite graph on $2n$ vertices with valency $k>0$.

> Prove that a coclique $C$ has size at most $n$, and that if $G$ is connected, equality 
>   can only hold if $C$ is one of the two bipartite classes.

I have a proof for this, but it relies on the Hoffman bound, and the characterization in case of equality.
Surely there must be a much more simple proof, but I cannot find one?

I think one can use existence of perfect matchings to prove the upper bound, but then one still has to characterize those attaining the bounds.

Many thanks,
fred

Comment: Count the number of edges that join a vertex in $C$ to a vertex in its complement, and then think about the average valency of a vertex in the complement.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed very short, and in case of equality of connectedness, it also leads to the characterization!